# Cygwin: xterm not starting in user $HOME...?

Tags: cygwin, xterm, xming

I've got a working Xming / Cygwin installation set up on my Windows. Well, mostly...

I did set my home directory to /cygdrive/d in /etc/passwd. When I start the Cygwin Bash Shell (the pimped-up DOS window), this works - $HOME is set to /cygdrive/d, Cygwin finds my ~/.bash_profile, everything is fine.

*However*, when I start an `xterm`, it starts in `/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/<Username>`, and it does *not* source my .bash_profile, which is annoying as hell.

Sometime during this afternoon, it worked, and now it's broken, but for the life of me I cannot remember how I broke it.

Help?

**Edit:** Sorry, I should have been more precise. The xterm is started as `xterm -ls`, i.e. as login shell. It *does* find the global profile (because it runs a bash and sets $PS1 correctly), but it obviously gets confused about $HOME (and thus does not run ~/.bash_profile because it cannot find it).

I know a way or two to work around it, but I'd like to find the *cause* of this muckup, not fix the effects.

**Edit2:** Further testing showed that this - $HOME not being set according to /etc/passwd - happens *only when the application is started from the Xming / Xmingrc taskbar menu*. It's also contagious: Any sub-xterm started from a "broken" xterm opens in the wrong $HOME. Likewise the other way round: Any bash / xterm started *outside* the Xmingrc menu (that opens in the proper $HOME) can start sub-xterms that also are correct.

I'm a *bit* confused here.

Comment: Might HOME already be set to `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>` when xterm is invoked? That would override the `/etc/passwd` setting.

Comment: @ ak2: Can't be, really. When I start the Cygwin Bash Shell (DOS box), HOME is set correctly. And it doesn't matter whether I start the xterm from that bash shell or directly through a destop shortcut. But I will double-check this tomorrow (it's my office workstation I'm talking about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer hidden in the Xming documentation. If no `HOME` environment variable is set in the system, *Xming sets it to `%USERPROFILE%`*.

Which in turn overrides the Cygwin `/etc/passwd` settings, as ak2 pointed out.

So, the solution is to manually set HOME in the control panel.

Comment: Or use Cygwin's own X server instead of Xming. (It's the xorg-server package in setup.exe.)

Answer (score 0):

`xterm` starts in the current directory and executes the program you tell it to execute (your preferred shell by default, but not a login shell). That's true on Windows as well as Unix. If you want to have a login shell, run `xterm -e bash --login`. If you want to start in your home directory, set the directory field in the shortcut (assuming you're starting xterm from a Windows shortcut).

Comment: See updated question, sorry.